# Android Importing Project -- FloatingActionButton cannot be found

Tags: android, import, importerror, floating-action-button

I am attempting to import a project located at: https://github.com/lancevalour/Rise/tree/master/res

but upon attempted import, Android Studio errors out and simply notes:

```
* Project Rise:G:\Hard Disk Downloads\Rise-master\Rise-master\project.properties:
Library reference ..\FloatingActionButton could not be found
Path is G:\Hard Disk Downloads\Rise-master\Rise-master\..\FloatingActionButton which resolves to G:\Hard Disk Downloads\Rise-master\FloatingActionButton
```

How can I ensure this project is imported successfully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your gradle - "build.grade" file

```
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.1'
```

[image]

Hope it helps, best of luck :)